# Symfony2 Selenium Behat base_url not loaded

Tags: java, php, symfony, selenium

I am setting up a testing env for an application in symfony2 but I get some errors that I don't find a coherent answer online...

> composer json

```
"require-dev": {
  ...
  "behat/symfony2-extension": "^2.1",
  "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "^1.3",
  "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "@stable",
  "behat/mink-extension": "@stable",
  "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3"
},
```

> behat.yml - old one

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: 'http://myapp.lan/app_test.php/'
            browser_name: firefox
            default_session: selenium2
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
            javascript_session: selenium2

        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
```

> behat.yml - new one

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~

        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://myapp.lan/app_test.php/
            browser_name: firefox
            sessions:
                goutte:
                    goutte: ~
                selenium2:
                    selenium2: ~
                symfony2:
                    symfony2: ~
            javascript_session: selenium2
    suites:
        site:
            type: symfony_bundle
            bundle: SiteBundle
            mink_session: symfony2
            contexts:
                - MyApp\SiteBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
```

> feature

```
Feature: Test login of users

  @javascript
  Scenario: Login to application
    Given: I am on "/"
      Then I should see "Login"
```

I am using

- `selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.50.1.jar`.
- Firefox 44 installed in my OS (Linux Mint)

The browser starts but there no url triggered.

[image]

As you see the url input is empty and after few seconds the browser closes with the test failing.

When i run `echo $this->getSession()->getCurrentUrl();` I get `about:blank` so obviously `base_url` is ignored.

If i enter the url manually then everything is OK.

I don't have a VM or something else installed just a linux box with latest version of firefox/chrome and latest version of selenium which is also my dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that this example worked for me. Got it from [Installing behat3 with composer.json](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/v2zi/installing-behat3-with-composer-json)

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "behat/behat" : "3.0.15",
        "behat/symfony2-extension" : "2.0.0",
        "behat/mink": "1.6.1",
        "behat/mink-extension": "2.0.1",
        "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "1.2.0",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "1.1.0",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "1.2.0"
    }
}
```

**behat.yml**

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension: ~
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: http://myapp.lan/app_test.php
            browser_name: firefox
            sessions:
                goutte:
                    goutte: ~
                selenium2:
                    selenium2: ~
                symfony2:
                    symfony2: ~
    suites:
        backend:
            type: symfony_bundle
            bundle: ApplicationBackendBundle #Change this with your
            mink_session: symfony2
            contexts:
                - Application\BackendBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext: #Change this with your
                    param1: hello
                    param2: world
```

**FeatureContext**

```
namespace Application\BackendBundle\Features\Context;

use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    private $param1;
    private $param2;

    public function __construct($param1, $param2)
    {
        $this->param1 = $param1;
        $this->param2 = $param2;
    }
}
```

**Gherkin**

```
Feature: Visit pages and see contents

  Scenario: I visit home page and see welcome message
    Given I am on "/"
    Then I should see "Welcome to Application!"

  Scenario: I visit contact page and see contact message
    Given I am on "/contact"
    Then I should see "Contact me!"
```

### ADDITION

Selenium and Firefox have compatibility issues that I myself experienced before. If you Google, you'll see similar posts. Try in this order:

1. Try `selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar` version. https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.43/
2. Try Chrome browser by using chromedriver. [Running selenium server standalone and chromedriver](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/js7k/running-selenium-server-standalone-and-cromedriver)

You should really go through http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/behat for examples.

Comment: no it's not working. the problem is that the browser starts but the url is not filled up. If i enter it manually then the tests run and it finds some text I am searching for in the *.feature. Yes, the browser is installed, I can access my app and I am using behat3

Comment: Add your feature steps please.

Comment: I updated the answer so it is for Behat3 now and it worked fine for me.

Comment: It is classic Selenium and Firefox compatibility issue. See ADDITIONAL section above.

Comment: I was trying the 2nd point as well this morning and instead of an url I get data;. instead of an url.

Comment: You need to add chrome browser related bits to behat.yml. You can find what they are in the blog site I posted above. But just try with step 1 first. You may not need step 2 at all. In most cases, 2.43.1 version makes things work. At least it did for me.

Comment: ok, what version of FF are you using? I am using FF44. I downgraded to 28.0 which is in the apt-cache but still does not work. I guess selenium 2.43.1 should work with a specific version of FF...

Comment: I cannot remember. It was at least 1 year ago! If my memory is good, I think I had problem with F44 as well but didn't downgraded it.